If two points at different radial distances from the centre of a rotating disk have different LATERAL speeds, how can they be at rest with each other?
I know the rotating disk is an accelerated frame, but if that is the cause I want to know how exactly  this eliminates the difference in their lateral speeds that is observed in an inertial frame.

Which part of the standard explanation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame) did you find unsatisfactory?

Thanks for the link. I will study it to further educate myself.

The transformation from the inertial frame to the non-inertial frame subtracts different velocities at different points in space. It subtracts a larger velocity from the faster point so that they both become stationary.

Thanks. Your response comes closest to answering my particular need. But now to a further query. A person at the centre of the disk is at rest w.r.t both the disk and an inertial observer, and yet they determine two different lateral speeds of a point on the rim. This doesn't happen in other cases. E.g., if a person on a moving train has to be at rest w.r.t. a railroad observer he has to MOVE suitably w.r.t the train; moreover, they  will then determine the SAME speed of all objects inside and outside the train. Any real difference here? Or should I just get used to a counterintuitive truth?

Maybe you are confused because the distance between the two points is constant, but not they relative position.
Velocity is the derivative of position over time
$ \vec{v}_1 = \frac{\vec{r}_1}{dt} \hspace{1cm} \vec{v}_2 = \frac{\vec{r}_2}{dt} $
So if you look for the change rate of the relative position vector $\vec{r}_{12} = \vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_1$ you can calculate $\vec{v}_{12} = \frac{\vec{r}_{12}}{dt} = \vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1$.
In a circular motion in 2D:
$ \vec{r}_1 = R_1[sin(\omega t),cos(\omega t)] \hspace{1cm} \vec{r}_2 = R_2[sin(\omega t),cos(\omega t)] $
$\vec{r}_{12} = (R_2-R_1)[sin(\omega t),cos(\omega t)]$
So the relative velocity is non-zero: $\vec{v}_{12} = \omega(R_2-R_1)[cos(\omega t),-sin(\omega t)]$, even if you take the modulus of the vector $|\vec{v}_{12}| = \omega(R_2-R_1)$. But is perpendicular to the direction of $r_{12}$ which means that the relative position is spinning.
But if you calculate the distance $|\vec{r}_{12}|$:
$|\vec{r}_{12}| = (R_2-R_1)\sqrt{sin^2(\omega t)+cos^2(\omega t)} = (R_2-R1)$
You can notice that is not a function of time, so the derivative of distance is 0 and the two points never get closer.
This means that the radial velocity between the two points is zero, but relative velocity have a non-zero component.
